# AppleScript droplet that moves file

Tags: applescript

trying to make an AppleScript droplet that moves a file to a given folder when the file is dragged to the droplet; not sure how to tell the script that the file I just dragged is the one I want to move; I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
on open dragged_file
  tell application "Finder"
  move dragged_file to "Macintosh HD:Users...etc."
  end tell
end open   --script runs but doesn't move file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
on open of theFiles
    tell application "Finder"
        move theFiles to folder "Macintosh HD:Users...etc."
    end tell
end open
```

Comment: Sweet!!!! (how do I know the syntax is "on open of the Files" instead of "on open theFiles" ?)

Comment: The "of" does not make a difference. Your problem was that you did not include "folder" in front of the HFS path.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Please accept the answer so other users know the question is no longer open.

Answer (score 0):

To use a droplet, you have to introduce a loop  repeat with currentitem in draggeditem
now your script
And then end repeat
for your exemple

```
on open dragged_file
 repeat with currentitem in dragged_file
  tell application "Finder"
  move dragged_file to folder "Macintosh HD:Users...etc."
  end tell
end repeat
end open   --script runs but doesn't move file
```